# Awk for selecting rows with columns that share a value

Tags: shell, awk

I have a table resembling the following one (but much longer):

```
A     B        C          D           E
1     YRI_1    YRI_2      10761       0  
2     YRI_3    YRI_3      7825        0  
3     YRI_1    YRI_4      9880        0  
4     YRI_1    Medit_1    79707       0  
5     YRI_2    Medit_2    73865       0  
6     YRI_2    Medit_3    77165       0  
7     YRI_3    Medit_4    76428       0  
8     YRI_3    CHB_1      8273        0  
9     YRI_2    CHB_2      10668       0  
10    YRI_1    CHB_3      8391        0
```

I would like to obtain:

```
A     B        C          D           E
2     YRI_3    YRI_3      7825        0
4     YRI_1    Medit_1    79707       0  
5     YRI_2    Medit_2    73865       0  
9     YRI_2    CHB_2      10668       0
```

i.e. I would like to keep those rows whose numbers in columns B and C only match, for example YRI_1 / Medit_1 both have a "1" so it is a wanted row, but I would not like to keep for example YRI_1 / Medit_10, since this is "10" although it contains a "1".

I tried with awk:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
   awk '$2=="*$i"||$3=="*$i" {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' table > desired_table
done
```

where $i was supposed to be substituted in each iteration by the next number in the list 1..4, and also I pretended * to mean anything, because I am interested in the number (but I guess this is not the way to do it with awk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'split($2, a, /_/) && split($3, b, /_/) && a[2] == b[2]' file

A     B        C          D           E
2     YRI_3    YRI_3      7825        0
4     YRI_1    Medit_1    79707       0
5     YRI_2    Medit_2    73865       0
9     YRI_2    CHB_2      10668       0
```

- We use 2 `split` functions to split `$2` and `$3` and then compare 2nd fields of split array for equality.
- `split` returns number of elements in the resulting array. By using `awk 'split($2, a, /_/) && split($3, b, /_/) &&` we are making sure that `split` is returning non-zero values.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning the return value of `split` (i.e. the number of elements in the array), which you're currently relying on for `&&` to work.

Comment: Yes that's right since we are going to compare `a[2]` and `b[2]` we need `split` to return non-zero

Comment: And this worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. I am trying to understand the syntax, would it be correct if I say that first you call the 2nd column "a" and the 3rd "b" and state that the separator is a "_", and then you ask for the lines whose columns "a" and "b" have the same 2nd element (i.e., the number)?

Comment: Yes we split 2nd column into array `a` using delimiter `_`. Then we split 3rd column into array `b` using delimiter `_`. Finally we compare 2nd element of arrays using `a[2] == b[2]`

Answer (score 1):

Remove all chars except numbers ([^0-9]) from related cols and print if they match.

```
awk 'NR==1 || (gensub(/[^0-9]/,"","g",$2)==gensub(/[^0-9]/,"","g",$3))' file
A     B        C          D           E
2     YRI_3    YRI_3      7825        0
4     YRI_1    Medit_1    79707       0
5     YRI_2    Medit_2    73865       0
9     YRI_2    CHB_2      10668       0
```